# Horizontal line in index to separate appendices

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to separate my chapters from my appendices in my index.
I would like to have something like that (red line) :
[image]

For now, my code is like this. I don't want my index to have a page number, that is why my code looks like this.

```
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{0}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

...
```

I have no idea how to do that. Can you help me ?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX stack exchange! Please be sure to include a [minimal, working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/188049) of the code you want changed, so we can better assist you. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! you might be able to get something quite simple with the `\addcontentsline` command

Comment: @cmhughes - Actually, \addtocontents would work better.  \addcontentsline would add the page number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks a lot !
The line :

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip \HRule }
```

solved my issue.